# Clickable link to local folder in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, pdf, hyperlink, r-markdown, knitr

I was wondering if it is possible to add a link of a local directory or file to rmarkdown. My goal is to have a png in each page, and a clickable link on some of the pages that take me to the file that plots are generated from (special file, so no csv, or tables).I don't want to open the file, but just open the folder that has that file, so user can easily find it and open it with appropriate software.
Something like this:

```
 {r, results='asis'}
 #Generate some plots
  for (i1 in 1:10)
 {  
   png(paste0("~/Downloads/tmp-png/",i1,".png"), width=800, height=800)
   par(mfrow=c(3,3))
   for (j1 in 1:9)
     plot(1:40)
   dev.off()
   }
  some.list <- c("2.png","5.png","7.png")
  files <- list.files(path = "~/Downloads/tmp-png", pattern = "png", 
  full.names = TRUE)
  for (f in files) {
    cat(paste0("![image_label](", f, ")\n"))
    if ( f %in% some.list)
    #Add a local hyperlink to the folder
   #
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what the link should be, but you should be able to generate one using something like your image inclusion.  E.g. if the link you want for file `f` is to folder `temp/foo.wjx`, then just include

```
folder <- "temp/foo.wjx"
cat(paste0("[folder_label](", folder, ")\n"))
```

after the `if`.

This needs to be a folder on the web server with a path relative to the path to the PDF file making the link.  Whether the PDF viewer follows the link probably depends on which viewer you are using.

The `folder_label` could be an image link instead of a text label.

Comment: I fixed some.list. The link is just a local path (i.e. ./temp/foo.wjx)  to a file, that is in the same directory as my knitr file. I want to add this hyperlink to my knitr pdf, so that there is text "folder_label" in my page 2,5 and 7 that takes me to some file in the directory.

Comment: Thank you! It works if I have the foo.wjx. But the problem is that it tries to open it in my browser rather than open it with a folder viewer. When I right-click on the folder_label I can see that the link is ./temp/foo.wjx.
 When I change my folder to be just "./temp", I get an error after clicking on the link that temp.pdf does not exist.

I am on ubuntu using document viewer for pdf (Foxit does not do anything at all), which may be the problem.

Comment: I suspect that `"./temp/"` (with the final slash) might be better than leaving it off (though it doesn't work for me, it really does depend on the viewer).  I also suspect that no viewer will let you run arbitrary commands on your system; that would be too much of a security risk.

Comment: With the final slash, it still tries to open a temp.pdf wichi does not exist.
The new xfun package in knitr, has the option of embedding files or folders, but that one tries to download the files, and I don't want to do that. I think as you said because of security reason that may not be possible. I tried to change the default browser in evince to be nautilus, instead of firefox, but still it gets open in firefox.